# Error Git push The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, push, configuración

- Creo una carpeta nueva en mi pc en **C:\Users\Equipo\Desktop\prueba**
- Luego voy a la consola "Cmder" y creo nuevo repositorio haciendo **λ git init**
- Luego cambio de usuario para este proyecto: **git config user.name gonzalezeduardo01** (es mi usuario de git de esta cuenta que quiero utilizar)
- Luego cambio email: **git config user.email eddug1983@gmail.com** (este email estoy regisrado en git)
- Luego agrego los archivos: **git add .**
- Luego commit: **git commit -m "primera carga"**
- Luego: **git remote add origin https://github.com/gonzalezeduardo01/prueba01.git**
- Luego: **git push -u origin master --force**

Y aparece el error:
**remote: Permission to gonzalezeduardo01/prueba01.git denied to eduardomgonzalez.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gonzalezeduardo01/prueba01.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403**

*Aclaraciones:* Yo en mis credenciales de windows me fije y estoy con mi otra cuenta de Git (**no se si esto tiene que ver**). Pero pense que dentro de la carpera del proyecto cambiando el usuario y la contraseña con **git config username** y con **git config user.email** ya me solucionaba todo y podria hacer el push sin problemas a la cuenta donde quiero depositar el proyecto, pero no, me aparecio el error.
No se si fui claro en la explicacion. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar...Se los agradeceria. Saludos!

Comment: En el push dice que el usuario eduardomgonzalez no tiene acceso al repositorio

Answer (score 1):

No es la mejor solucion pero puedes cambiar el la url del repositorio remoto de esta forma:

```
git remote set-url origin https://gonzalezeduardo01@github.com/gonzalezeduardo01/prueba01.git
```

De este modo especificas que el acceso lo haras con el usuario 'gonzalezeduardo01' y te pedira la contraseña de ese usuario.

Comment: Gracias!!!. Tratare de hacer eso...

Answer (score 0):

El problema son las credenciales, debes ingresar a credenciales de windows o de linux respectivamente y modificar el acceso a gitlab, en el casod e estar usando otra cuenta, pones la nueva cuenta y todo solucionado.

Comment: Por favor, detalla más esa respuesta y pon paso a paso lo que hay que hacer, pues la frase que has escrito no ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

simple busca en San Google como entrar a las credenciales del Windows que tengas , buscas el de github , le das editar y cambia el usuario y la contraseña y listo , cierras y abres el editor de texto y queda ok.

Sígueme para mas soluciones.

https://github.com/jcado

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a [ES.so], por favor lee [answer] para que tus respuestas sean mejor recibidas